# Several elements use the same css class, how can I change the css properties of only one of those elements

Tags: javascript

I am creating a little game that should be like a 2d version of "guitar hero" (if you don't know what "guitar hero" is don't worry, it was just to give context). I have a red square creator function called `squareCreator` that adds each `new` square created a CSS class of `.newMostLeftNote`. Afterward, I want each one of those squares to fall down (like gravity) using the function `fallingMostLeftNote`. The problem is that the `margin-top` that function adds to the square generated by the `squareCreator` adds to every single square at the same time (even before the square is created), so a square could be created when the `.newMostLeftNote` CSS class has a margin-top of 700 and it appears way at the bottom.

How can I make it so that every square that falls, but starts falling after they appear?

[image]

Notice that in this image, every `margin-top` CSS property for every `new` generated square is exactly the same.

```js
var mostLeftNoteMarginTop = 0;


function squareCreator(){
  var newNote = document.createElement("div");
  newNote.className = "newMostLeftNote";
  document.body.appendChild(newNote);
}

var generationSpeed = setInterval(squareCreator, 300);


function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  mostLeftNoteMarginTop += 2;
  $(".newMostLeftNote").css({
    'margin-top': mostLeftNoteMarginTop + 'px'
  });
}

proc = setInterval(fallingMostLeftNote, 5);
```

```css
.newMostLeftNote {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mostLeftNote {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

.middleNote {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mostRightNote {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 900px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Score: 0</h1>
  <div class="middleNote"></div>
  <div class="mostLeftNote"></div>
  <div class="mostRightNote"></div>
  <div class="scoreLineTop"></div>
  <div class="scoreLineButtom"></div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

Update

```
var squareQuantity = [];


function squareCreator(){
  var newNote = document.createElement("div");
  newNote.className = "newMostLeftNote";
  document.body.appendChild(newNote);
  squareQuantity.push(this.newNote);
}

var generationSpeed = setInterval(squareCreator, 300);


function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  mostLeftNoteMarginTop += 2;
  squareQuantity[2].css({
    'margin-top': mostLeftNoteMarginTop + 'px'
  });
}
```

Comment: `$(".newMostLeftNote").first()`

Comment: Thanks, it works for the first one only, but how can I make it so that every next square that appears also falls, but starts falling after they appear.

Comment: Loop perhaps? .

Comment: I have pushed every new square created into an array, instead of first(), can I select which one I want to use from the array?

Comment: Sure. Even randomly.

Comment: Would you take a look at the update please (at the very buttom of my post). It does not seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222681/discussion-between-wiseeye-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Sorry I am offline now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to update your margin-top, you could use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). Each new square will animate independently.

Here's an example for your use case:

```js
function addSquare() {
  var squaresElement = document.getElementById("squares");
  var squareElement = document.createElement("div");
  squareElement.className = "square";
  squaresElement.append(squareElement);
}
```

```css
#squares {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: fall;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

/* The animation code */
@keyframes fall {
  from {margin-top: 0px;}
  to {margin-top: 300px;}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSquare()">Add square</button>
<div id="squares"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is giving a css variable while creating divs for transform delay. If you need more complex movements, you can use the same logic for animation instead of transform.

```
<div class="parent"></div>
```

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.lets-try {
  flex: 1;
  background: #000;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out var(--delay);
}

.lets-try.is-falling {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```
let parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
let numOfSquares = 12;
for (let i = 0; i < numOfSquares ; i++) {
  let delay = i * 0.2;
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'lets-try');
  div.setAttribute('style', `--delay:${delay}s`);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
setTimeout(() => {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".lets-try");
  [...items].forEach(item => {
    item.classList.add("is-falling")
  })
}, 1)
```